# testing nonlinear hypothesis glm R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, probit, nonlinear

I estimate probit model: 
\begin{align*}
P(y=1|x_1, x_2, x_3) = \Phi(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2+ \alpha_3 x_3) 
\end{align*}
using: `probitMain <- glm(y~x1+x2+x3, family=binomial(link="probit"), data=MD)`.
I want to test nonlinear hypothesis $f(\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) = 0$,
where $f$ is a rational function $f(\alpha_0,\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3) = \frac{\alpha_2 + \alpha_0 \frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_1}}{1+\frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_1}}$. 
I have tried to use [nlWaldTest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nlWaldTest/index.html) package for nonlinear Wald test,  but it doesn't seem to work with *glm* objects.

Is there any other R package that can test nonlinear hypothesis for *glm*?

Comment: What's the rational function? Some functions at least will allow manipulations that simplify the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have included the explicit definition of the function in the question.

Comment: If $a_1\neq 0$ then you can multiply numerator and denominator by $a_1$ and get: 

$f = \frac{a_2a_1 + a_0a_3}{a_1 + a_3}$. Now if $(a_1+a_3)\neq 0$ then

$f=0$ if $a_2a_1 + a_0a_3 = 0$. That's still nonlinear, but it is at least a little simpler.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I have manipulated the likelihood function for probit so it can be written in the suitable form and estimated parameters using max likelihood and retrieved the appropriate standard errors.

Comment: Do you think what you did might work as a kind of answer for your question? I'm thinking mainly that if there are other people with a similar problem describing what you ended up doing to solve the problem might be useful.

Comment: I do it like this:  Write the probability as: $P(Y=1|x_1, x_2, x_3)= \Phi \left( \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 x_1 + (\gamma_3 + \gamma_3 \gamma_4 - \gamma_1)x_2 + \gamma_2 \gamma_4 x_3\right)$. I estimate this equation using ML wrp to $\gamma$'s. Note that $\gamma_2$ is exactly the parameter I was interested in. From Hessian of ML estimation I can retrieve the standard errors.

Comment: Could you post your answer as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem like this.  Write the probit equation as: 
\begin{align}
P(y=1|x_1, x_2, x_3)=\Phi \left(\gamma_1 + \gamma_2 x_1 + (\gamma_3 + \gamma_3 \gamma_4 -\gamma_1)x_2 + \gamma_2 \gamma_4 x_3 \right)
\end{align}
I estimate this equation using ML with respect to $\gamma's$ (with function mle2 from ***bbmle*** package). Note that $\gamma_2$ is exactly the parameter I was originally interested in. From Hessian of the ML estimation I can retrieve standard errors.